# Progress Dialog is not shown during execution of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I googled for hours and tried all answers of Stack Overflow  but didn't solved my problem.

I made android program to download data in bytes which wroks perfectly. And for download working on background thread. I want to show a Progress Dialog(jus Spinning one). But I'm having really annoying problem. My download takes about 5 sec but my progress dialog is either not shown or just shown for last 1 sec.

Here's my code for AsyncTask.

```
public class ImageJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, byte[]> {

private JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
private byte[] response;

 private ProgressDialog pg; 
 private Context context; 

 public ImageJSON(Activity activity) {
     pg = new ProgressDialog(activity);
 }
@Override 
protected void onPreExecute() { 
    super.onPreExecute();
    pg.setMessage("Downloading, please wait.");
    pg.show(); 
} 

@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    if (pg != null) { 
        pg.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0])); 
    } 
}

protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) { 
    if (pg.isShowing()) { 
        pg.dismiss(); 
    } 
}
@Override
protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("my file url....");
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("imageId", params[0]);

        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
        httpPost.addHeader("Content_Type", "application/octet_stream");
        httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity!=null) {
            response = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
            entity.consumeContent();
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    } catch (JSONException|IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

And I called it from my activity using this code.

```
final ImageJSON imageTask = new ImageJSON(ReaderActivity.this);
byte[] response = imageTask.execute(imageId).get();
```

If anybody can help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: just try whether the progress dialog is appearing when we comment onprogressupdate method ?

Comment: dont call execute().get(); it will block UI

Comment: uncommenting onProgressUpdate didn't helped but removing get() method do the trick....thnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to be using `get()` as it still freezes your UI thread thus denying the sense of using `AsyncTask`. You might want to implement `onPostExecute` in order to return your result properly.

Comment: I got it... get() was freezing UI thread...using onPostExecute to process the result better than using jsonObj.getString()......thnx

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
public ImageJSON(Activity activity) {

 }
@Override 
protected void onPreExecute() { 
    super.onPreExecute();
pg = new ProgressDialog(ReaderActivity.this);
    pg.setMessage("Downloading, please wait.");
    pg.show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to initilise your progressDialogue in onPreExecute method

```
@Override 
protected void onPreExecute() { 
    super.onPreExecute();
pg = new ProgressDialog(pass_context_here);
    pg.setMessage("Downloading, please wait.");
    pg.show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
public ImageJSON(Context ctx) {
 this.context = ctx;

}
```

Now in your `onPreExecute()` method use this

```
@Override 
protected void onPreExecute() { 
 super.onPreExecute();
 pg = new ProgressDialog(context);
 pg.setMessage("Downloading, please wait.");
 pg.show(); 
 }
```

You'r initializing your `ProgressDialog` in `ImageJSON` class which block your UI thread means freezes it. So need to initialize it in `onPreExecute()` method with reference of context.

Comment: An Activity is a Context, so there is no difference. Also, `onPreExecute()` is run on the UI thread, so that is not different, either.

Comment: I Know that it is the same. According to OPs question this will be my answer.